# CGRectIntersectsRect logic inaccuracy

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cgrect

In an app I give random frames to squares every time it is run. I use this logic to make sure

a) each square is not too close to the player
and
b) each square is contained inside the view of the screen
c) no square touches any other square

```
for(UIButton* button in squareArray) {
    BOOL shouldContinue = YES;
    do {
        int randX = arc4random() % 321;
        int randY = arc4random() % 481;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(randX, randY, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
        CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(100, 180, 120, 120);
        for(UIButton* b in squareArray)
            if(!CGRectIntersectsRect(b.frame, button.frame) && 
                !CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, playerRect) && 
                CGRectContainsRect(self.view.frame, button.frame)) {
                shouldContinue = NO;
            }
    } while (shouldContinue);
}
```

With this code, I would expect that each square in squareArray would be (once the loop was complete) completely inside the boundaries of the view, not intersecting with any other of the buttons in the array, and completely outside the boundaries of the playerRect rect, which is a square 120 x 120 in the center of the screen. Is my code wrong? Because I get none of these functionalities.

Edit: I do in fact get one of the desired traits of this method: no square ever intersects playerRect. But I still get squares overlapping each other and squares that are partially out of the view.

Edit 2:

I have made these changes to the nested for loop:

```
for(UIButton* b in squareArray)
            if(![b isEqual:button]) {
                if(CGRectIntersectsRect(b.frame, button.frame) || 
                   CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, playerRect) || 
                   !CGRectContainsRect(CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 460), button.frame))
                    shouldContinue = YES;
                else
                    shouldContinue = NO;
            }
```

And now the squares always are within the slightly modified (smaller) rect for the view, and they never intersect the player square. Yay. But they still appear on top of each other. Why?

Comment: You didn't state a question or explain what you think is wrong with your code.

Comment: Bahahaha I'm sorry I accidentally posted it before actually asking a question because I was in a rush. Updating now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this worked: (a combination of the wonderful answers of Rob Lourens and rob mayoff- thanks guys, and here, each of you have an upvote! :) )

```
for(int iii = 0; iii < [squareArray count]; iii++) {

    int randX = arc4random() % 321;
    int randY = arc4random() % 481;

    [(UIButton*)[squareArray objectAtIndex:iii] setFrame:CGRectMake(randX, randY, [(UIButton*)[squareArray objectAtIndex:iii] frame].size.width, [(UIButton*)[squareArray objectAtIndex:iii] frame].size.height)];

    CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(40, 120, 150, 150);

    for(UIButton* b in squareArray)

        if(![b isEqual:[squareArray objectAtIndex:iii]]) {

            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(b.frame, [(UIButton*)[squareArray objectAtIndex:iii] frame]))
            {
                iii--;
                break;
            } else if(CGRectIntersectsRect([(UIButton*)[squareArray objectAtIndex:iii] frame], playerRect)) {
                iii--;
                break;
            } else if(![self checkBounds:[(UIButton*)[squareArray objectAtIndex:iii] frame]]) {
                iii--;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with `CGRectIntersectsRect`, it's a problem with your logic. When the inner loop finds a single UIButton that does not intersect button, you accept the random coords generated for button. You need to ensure that all the buttons in squareArray don't intersect button, not just one.

Also, what are the frames of the buttons initialized to? Maybe this would be a better solution:

```
for (int i=0; i<[squareArray count]; i++) {
    UIButton* button = [squareArray objectAtIndex:i];
    BOOL shouldContinue = NO;
    do {
        int randX = arc4random() % 321;
        int randY = arc4random() % 481;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(randX, randY, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
        CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(100, 180, 120, 120);
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            UIButton *b = [squareArray objectAtIndex:j];
            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(b.frame, button.frame) || 
                CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, playerRect) || 
                !CGRectContainsRect(self.view.frame, button.frame)) {
                shouldContinue = YES;
            }
    } while (shouldContinue);
}
```

Note that I haven't tested that at all. Also, depending on the situation, this could loop forever if there is no valid position for a button. There may be a better solution than placing everything completely randomly, depending on your problem.

Comment: The frames are initialized through IB, because each square in squareArray is an IBOutlet to a UIButton, so they all have default positions, and I just want to randomize them.

Comment: Are you sure you've got all squares in the squareArray? If they're from a nib, maybe there are some that you're not repositioning?

Comment: No; I know that the proper number of squares is being loaded into the array because at startup, depending on the number of squares that *should* be in the array (depending on user selection), those squares are hard-coded into the array. Also, since the same array is being used both times, if it did not include all of the squares (there are four) then all of them would not be put in random positions each time, and they are.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `squareArray` contains three buttons A, B, and C with these frames:

```
A.frame == CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)
B.frame == CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)
C.frame == CGRectMake(20,10,10,10)
```

Note that A and B overlap, but A and B do not overlap C.  Now consider what happens in your inner loop when `button == B`.

On the first pass through the inner loop, `b == A`, so you detect `CGRectIntersectsRect(b.frame, button.frame)` and set `shouldContinue = YES`.

On the second pass, `b == B` which means `[b isEqual:button]`, so you do nothing.

On the third (and final) pass, `b == C`.  You find that `CGRectIntersectsRect(b.frame, button.frame)` is false (because `B.frame` does not intersect `C.frame`), and `CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, playerRect)` is false, and `!CGRectContainsRect(CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 460), button.frame)` is false.  So you set `shouldContinue = NO`.

Then the inner loop exits.  You test `shouldContinue`, find that it's false, and exit the do/while loop.  You have left button B overlapping button A.

Comment: So, in other words, remove the line where you set shouldContinue = NO.

Comment: I have a long explanation for why that wouldn't work, and I was about to post it and ask for more help, but then I decided to tough it out and figure it out my self. Removing that line wouldn't work because even once the condition is satisfied, shouldContinue is still YES from the time it wasn't satisfied, and you get an infinite loop. I have just posted the working solution.